# How to upload a file on server in c# fastly than this

Tags: c#

Currently i am using following code , is there any better (means fast) way to upload a file, here is my complete code, it is called at each file upload:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("request_uri_string");
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("path_to_my_file",
                                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream(); 
byte[] buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096,
                            (int)fileStream.Length))];   
int bytesRead = 1;
while (bytesRead != 0)
{
    bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} 
requestStream.Close();
fileStream.Close();
String responseFromServer = null;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription.Contains("OK"))
{
   Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(((HttpWebResponse)response).CharacterSet);
   Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, encode);
   responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
   reader.Close();
   dataStream.Close();
}
response.Close();
```

Comment: That code wouldn't compile (`close` rather than `Close`) which suggests this isn't your real code...

Comment: Define "faster". Less lines, or better connection's bandwidth usage?

Comment: @jon ,  it is manually written. That's why written close instead of Close by mistake, please help

Comment: @ quetzalcoat Faster means better connection's bandwidth usage , means upload file as soon as possible

Comment: Well how long does your *current* code take, for what size of file?

Comment: @jon , Infact i am comparing it with a mac application, which uploads the same file on same server faster than my code.

Comment: @kapill: And what is that comparison like? A bit faster, or much, much faster? Are the Mac and your computer running this code on the same network? There's so much more information you could be giving us...

Comment: @jon : it is on same network ,and mac is uploading around 350 txt files having size 1 kb in 3 minutes where as windows code it uploads just 50 such files in same time. So mac is much much faster than my code.

Comment: @jon: Each file has less than 1 kb size

Comment: @kapill: Do you have anything to get the *response* from the request, and close that response? If not, that could be *very* relevant... It would really help if you could post a short but *complete* program.

Comment: @jon: I have edited the post to add some more code regarding reading response from server, please...

Answer (score 4):

Probably not faster, but easier:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
//client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.UploadFile(uriString,fileName);
```